# failed to push some refs -tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart

Tags: github

I tried to push a file ("HelloWorld.md") on my local repository to remote repository on hithub. I got the following error message. How do I remove this error?

error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/kriaz100/DataScienceCours
era.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Answer (score 3):

Some changes were done remotely. For example you could change your `HelloWorld.md` using Github web UI

You have to merge local branch with origin recursively

Try

```
git pull origin your-branch-name -v
```

It will merge `origin` into your local branch.

Answer (score 3):

```
git pull --rebase 
git push origin master
```

The rebase will apply your changes after those already to the remote (online website).  This video literally goes over your exact issue and solves it using git pull --rebase https://youtu.be/IhkvMPE9Jxs?t=10m36s

Answer (score 0):

You can add -f parameter in `git` command

```
git push -f origin 'branch_name'
Example: 
git push -f origin main
```